# pls tell me how to make this query into a single query

Tags: sql

```
select ac1.ACCT_CODE,
       ac1.PERIOD,
       ac1.MONTH,
       ac1.YEAR,
       ac1.PRD_BDGT,
       ac2.ACCT_CODE,
       ac2.PERIOD,
       ac2.MONTH,
       ac2.YEAR,
       ac2.PRD_BDGT
from account ac1, account ac2
where ac1.acct_code='075200'
    and ac1.year=1994
    and ac1.period between 1 and 6
    and ac2.acct_code=ac1.acct_code
    and ac2.year=1995
    and ac2.period =ac1.period  

union 

select ac3.ACCT_CODE,
       ac3.PERIOD,
       ac3.MONTH,
       ac3.YEAR,
       ac3.PRD_BDGT,
       ac4.ACCT_CODE,
       ac4.PERIOD,
       ac4.MONTH,
       ac4.YEAR,
       ac4.PRD_BDGT
from account ac3, account ac4
where ac3.acct_code='075200'
     and ac3.year=1995
     and ac3.period between 7 and 12
     and ac4.acct_code=ac3.acct_code
     and ac4.year=1996
     and ac4.period=ac3.period
```

Comment: I would be surprised if this query actually does what you want.  As you can see, this question has not been well-received.  I would suggest that you ask another question, include sample data and desired output, and explain the problem you are actually trying to solve.

Answer (score 2):

Use an `OR`:

```
select ac1.ACCT_CODE,
ac1.PERIOD,
ac1.MONTH,
ac1.YEAR,
ac1.PRD_BDGT,
ac2.ACCT_CODE,
ac2.PERIOD,
ac2.MONTH,
ac2.YEAR,
ac2.PRD_BDGT
from account ac1, account ac2
where ac1.acct_code='075200'
    and ac2.acct_code=ac1.acct_code
    and ac2.period =ac1.period
and ((ac1.year=1994
    and ac1.period between 1 and 6
    and ac2.year=1995
 ) OR
    (ac1.year=1995
    and ac1.period between 7 and 12
    and ac2.year=1996))
```

Answer (score 2):

Your query is taking the `union` of two very similar queries, where the only difference is certain conditions in the `where` clause.  You can combine them pretty easily by using `or` in the `where` clause.

The following query also fixes the `join` syntax:

```
select ac1.ACCT_CODE, ac1.PERIOD, ac1.MONTH, ac1.YEAR, ac1.PRD_BDGT, ac2.ACCT_CODE,
       ac2.PERIOD, ac2.MONTH, ac2.YEAR, ac2.PRD_BDGT 
from account ac1 join
     account ac2 
     on ac2.period = ac1.period and
        ac2.acct_code = ac1.acct_code
where ac1.acct_code='075200' and
      ((ac1.year = 1994 and
        ac1.period between 1 and 6
        ac2.year=1995 
       ) or
       (ac1.year=1995 and
        ac1.period between 7 and 12 and
        ac2.year=1996
       )
      );
```

I would be surprised if this query actually solves your business problem.  Doing a self-join on the `accounts` table is suspicious.  Often, an aggregation is what one needs, but I cannot tell the purpose of the query.